# Route MVC 4 application url - css and js not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have done these much for routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Hidden1",
    url: "EditCategoryDetails/{categoryId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "TestController", action = "EditCategory", categoryId = UrlParameter.Optional 
});


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Hidden2",
    url: "CategoryDetails",
    defaults: new { controller = "TestController", action = "CategoryView" 
});

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "LoginController", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

After doin this the controller and action names were removed from the Url and were replaced by EditCategoryDetails and CategoryDetails respectively.

The problem is that after routing **js and css won't work** while the url is 
**localhost/mywebsite/CategoryDetails**

and is working when I place a **slash(//)** manually at the end of address bar

**localhost/mywebsite/CategoryDetails/**

After searching for the js and css  problem I have done this too

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.jpg");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.gif");
```

but no hope. Js and css get effected only when I manually add a **slash(/)** at the end on the address bar of browser.

Am including js and css in the _Layout.cshtml page as

```
  <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

etc.

Comment: can you post how you try to include js and css

Comment: Pls check. I have added dat too @VolodymyrBilyachat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it right. Some of the scripts of my website was reffered as

```
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```